# Session always returns null facebook php sdk

Tags: session, laravel, facebook-sdk-4.0

Hi I'm trying to get data from a user from facebook after he logs in whit facebook. But my session variable is always null .I'm currently using the laravel 4 framework. The code that you are seeing is being called as the callback function from facebook login.

```
$code = Input::get('code');
    if (strlen($code) == 0) return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'There was an error communicating with Facebook');

    $facebook = new Facebook(Config::get('facebook'));
    $uid = $facebook->getUser();

    if ($uid == 0) return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'There was an error');

    $me = $facebook->api('/me');

    $profile = Profile::whereUid($uid)->first();
    if (empty($profile)) {

        $user = new User;
        $user->name = $me['first_name'].' '.$me['last_name'];
        $user->email = $me['email'];
        $user->save();

        $profile = new Profile();
        $profile->uid = $uid;
        return $uid;
        $profile->username = $me['name'];
        $profile = $user->profiles()->save($profile);
    }

    $profile->access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
    $profile->save();

    $user = $profile->user;

    Auth::login($user);
    FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication(
        Config::get('facebook.appId'),
        Config::get('facebook.secret')
    );

    $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://projectweb.app:8000/');
    $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();

    if(isset($session))
    {
        $request = new FacebookRequest($session,'GET','/me');
        $response = $request->execute();
        $graph = $response->getGraphObject(GraphUser::classname());
        $name = $graph->getName();
        return $name;
    }
    else
    {
        return 'no sesssion';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You better try using a Laravel specific Package for that, here it is one, where you also have the details about installing and using it.

https://github.com/SammyK/LaravelFacebookSdk